# Apps Script email notification from cell changes in newly created document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script function (in sheet A) that creates a new document (call it sheet B), and sends it to someone else with ownership transfer.

```js
var createnew = SpreadsheetApp.create(newsheetname);
var copyID = createnew.getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyID);
file.setOwner('emailaddressxyz@email.com') // email is sent to new owner
```

Is it possible to track changes made in sheet B, e.g. by sending an email notification or updating a cell in the sheet A?

I know how to send email notifications and track changes in the same sheet, and I also know how to make changes from the script editor in sheet A to sheet B. But that doesn't help here, because sheet B does not have a script.

My first idea was to simply add a script to sheet B upon creating it, but that does not seem possible? Any ideas welcome, goal is to track changes in the new sheet without ever me having to manually access the script editor to this new sheet.

Comment: What kind of changes do you wish to track?

Comment: cell changes, e.g. a selection of an item in a drop down of a particular cell.

Comment: Well then the answer provided should do the trick as long as your only interested in changes resulting from user input.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to focus on is not so much a script (it's easy to create a spreadsheet with a script attached, by copying an existing blank spreadsheet with that script), as a *trigger*. A function triggered by edits to a spreadsheet need not be contained in a script bound to that spreadsheet. It can exist elsewhere, for example in your script that is creating a new spreadsheet. Example of [managing triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically):

```
var createnew = SpreadsheetApp.create(newsheetname);
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').forSpreadsheet(createnew).onEdit().create();
```

The trigger will run with the authorization of the user who created it. In particular, if it sends emails, they will be from your email account.